# Debian Full Disk Encryption: Does Debian Installer use LUKS 1 or 2?

Tags: debian, boot, encryption, luks

During installation, whenever I put `/boot` inside an LVM on top of LUKS along with swap, `/` and `/home`, afterwards when I try to boot into it, it only gives me the minimal bash-like `grub` terminal. This doesn't happen when `/boot` is left outside unencrypted.

I'm opting for FDE so I want `/boot` to be inside the LVM on LUKS. So what gives? I reckon Debian Installer uses LUKS 2 or otherwise it messes up the install in some other way that's beyond the scope of my knowledge. I tried to find similar threads but no luck.

Comment: you tell us... what does cryptsetup luksDump say

Answer (score 6):

As of Debian Buster, the installer uses the LUKS2 format. As described in the release notes...

> The cryptsetup version shipped with Debian buster uses the new on-disk
>   LUKS2 format. New LUKS volumes will use this format by default.
>
> **Please note that the GNU GRUB bootloader doesn't support the LUKS2
>   format yet.** See the corresponding documentation for further
>   information on how to install Debian 10 with encrypted boot. -source: https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#cryptsetup-luks2

The Debian [documentation](https://cryptsetup-team.pages.debian.net/cryptsetup/encrypted-boot.html) proceeds to describe work-arounds for getting full disk encryption to work on Buster.

Comment: FYI: grub2 got the support: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/commit/?id=365e0cc3e7e44151c14dd29514c2f870b49f9755, not yet in Debian unstable.